# LibVLC 1.9.8 implementation

Tags: android, libvlc

I am building an application where I need to implement libVLC in my project. I have used the latest compiled dependency of VLC lib i.e

```
compile "de.mrmaffen:vlc-android-sdk:1.9.8"
```

I have searched through internet but unfortunately I couldn't find any sample implementing the latest library.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm here in the same situation, but https://github.com/tomahawk-player/tomahawk-android implements this version.

Comment: Yes, I know , Thats why I have also implemented the older version only.